# owl-carousal doesn't show images

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

[image]here is my html code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.css">
<div id="owl-demo">        
                <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl1.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl2.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl3.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl4.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl5.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl6.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl7.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="assets/owl8.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
                autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
                items : 4,    
                itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
                itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
            });    

        });
    </script>
```

and that is the css

```
#owl-demo .item{
   margin: 3px;
}
#owl-demo .item img{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

and the carousal just display the indicators but not the images , and the console doesn't appear any errors , I tried alot but the problem doesn't solve ?

**note** : In Inspect Element .owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer when i make {overflow:visible} horizontal scroll appear and the images appear when you move the scroll to the left

see the problem here https://cde90a5c4d4962da8734f2f8af97a380e1d80b5d.googledrive.com/host/0B9nn9jFSK9EFMV9xOHctMm5zeHM/index.html

Comment: Are you sure that you have the right path for your images? have you already inspect the code?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#owl-demo .item img{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Use the height value in pixels

Comment: doesn't solve bro ,   note : In Inspect Element .owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer when i make {overflow:visible} horizontal scroll appear and the images appear when you move the scroll to the left

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the direction on my page is rtl , so you should download the rtl plugin version http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/rtl.html